# Stacked histogram for multi-category time-series

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have a time-series such as

```
smpl <- data.frame(year=c(1990,1991,1992,1993,1990,1991,1992,1993,1990,1991,1992,1993),
                   label=c(rep("Pear",4),rep("Apple",4),rep("Banana",4)),
                   value=c(10,9,8,7,2,3,4,5,12,14,5,6))
```

I want to create a time-series with bars indicating the relative value of labels for that year. I can obtain a similar-shape plot by dropping the `value` variable with

```
smpl <- data.frame(year=c(1990,1991,1992,1993,1990,1991,1992,1993,1990,1991,1992,1993),
                   label=c(rep("Pear",4),rep("Apple",4),rep("Banana",4)))

ggplot(smpl, aes(x=as.factor(year), fill=label)) + 
  geom_histogram(position="fill")
```

where each stack height is determined by the frequency of that label for the year.

[image]

How do I plug into the function a discrete `value` for the label? Should I reshape the dataframe?

Comment: `ggplot(smpl, aes(x = as.factor(year), y = value, fill = label)) + 
  geom_histogram(stat = "identity", position = "stack")` Like this?

Comment: @Khashaa Yes, and better still `ggplot(smpl, aes(x = as.factor(year), y = value, fill = label)) + geom_histogram(stat = "identity", position = "fill")`